# How to create Chart with 2 variables (x,,y)

Tags: php, html, charts, chart.js

I am looking forward chart like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6dAq.png with this code

php + html:

```
    $sql = "SELECT val1 , val2 ,t
FROM DvojeHodnoty
INNER JOIN Pristroje ON DvojeHodnoty.dev_name = Pristroje.dev_name
WHERE t>'$startdate2' AND t< '$enddate2' AND Pristroje.nazev_pristroje='$pristroj' order by val1 asc;";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $t =  $t.'"'.date('d.m.y H:i:s', $row['t']/1000).'",';
        $hodnota = $hodnota.'"'.$row['val1'].'",';
        $hodnota2 = $hodnota2.'"'.$row['val2'].'",';
    }
    $start = date('d.m.y', $startdate2/1000);
    $end = date('d.m.y', $enddate2/1000);
    $t = trim($t,",");
    $hodnota = trim($hodnota,",");
    $hodnota2 = trim($hodnota2,",");
}

<div id="chart-container" style="background: white">
        <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
        <script>
            var ctx =document.getElementById("chart").getContext('2d');
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type:'line',
                data: {
                    labels: [<?PHP  echo $hodnota2;  ?>],
                    datasets:
                        [
                            {
                                label: '<?PHP echo $start;?> - <?PHP echo $end; ?> Přístroj: <?PHP echo $pristroj;?>  ',
                                data: [<?PHP echo $hodnota; ?>],
                                backgroundColor:'transparent',
                                borderColor:'rgba(255,99,132)',
                                borderWidth: 3
                            }]

                },
                options: {
                    scales: {

                        yAxes:[{
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'σ',
                                fontSize: 20
                            }
                        }],
                        xAxes:[{
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'ε',
                                fontSize:20
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            })
        </script>
    </div>
```

but so far I got only this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri8Ho.png.

I don't know how to create chart with two variables, I tried scatter but so far I am stuck with no ability to create graph with x,y line as values. Is there any easy way to create chart with two variables? If so can you help me/ give me some documentation? (I've seen one scatter chart with fix values, but I am not able to do it with php echo (with values from database) since I need to have variable values since user will choose values depends on chosen date. So far I got only 1 value (y) and two values but with text (numbers counted as text not as value) so chart looks weirdly (0,1,-1 still on same line not like normal graph showned up).

Comment: With more values, I got this https://i.imgur.com/GhC5pcs.png and it's not sorted from -10 to 10 as you can see in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that data type was VARCHAR and for sorting it I need INT. Problem solved